SwiftUI presenting confirmationDialog from a toolbar popover
I have a regular confirmationDialog modifier in my main view:
.confirmationDialog("Please confirm",
    isPresented: $showConfirmLogout,
    titleVisibility: .visible) {
        Button("Logout") {
            showConfirmLogout = false
            userViewModel.logout()
        }
        Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
            showConfirmLogout = false
        }
    } message: {
        Text("Are you sure you want to logout?")
    }
}

I'm toggling on / off showConfirmLogout from a popover in the toolbar, which I don't know if it's the cause of my issue, but it seems the dialog is being displayed in the toolbar itself, where it's unable to render completely:
Is there any known way to tell the dialog to render outside the toolbar?


Please show a [mre]

Thank you @jndpx, I finally managed to get it working by moving the modifier under the toolbar button

In case someone faces a similar issue, I fixed it by moving the confirmationDialog modifier under the button in the toolbar (not the ones inside the popover).

